# open FDA Recalls API does not have same device class as accessdata.fda.gov

Tags: api, openfda

accessdata.fda.gov shows class 1 while api returns "device_class":2

examples
1)Baxter, SIGMA Spectrum
[https://api.fda.gov/device/recall.json?search=product_res_number:"Z-0530-2022"&limit=5&skip=0](https://api.fda.gov/device/recall.json?search=product_res_number:%22Z-0530-2022%22&limit=5&skip=0)

vs https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfRes/res.cfm?ID=190891

2)for Hospira, Plum A+
https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfRes/res.cfm?start_search=1&event_id=69336&productdescriptiontxt=&productcode=&rootCauseText=&centerclassificationtypetext=&recallnumber=&postdatefrom=&postdateto=04%2F12%2F2015&productshortreasontxt=&firmlegalnam=&PMA_510K_Num=&pnumber=&knumber=&sortcolumn=lnd

shows 5 below recalls as class 1:

Z-1071-2015, Z-1072-2015, Z-1073-2015, Z-1074-2015, Z-1075-2015
but api for each returns "device_class":2
[https://api.fda.gov/device/recall.json?search=product_res_number:"Z-1072-2015"&limit=5&skip=0](https://api.fda.gov/device/recall.json?search=product_res_number:%22Z-1072-2015%22&limit=5&skip=0)

Answer (score 1):

Class I that you see on the [FDA recall page](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfRes/res.cfm?ID=190891) is actually a classification of the recall itself:

> Class I - a situation in which there is a reasonable probability that
> the use of, or exposure to, a violative product will cause serious
> adverse health consequences or death.

The device itself is Class 2. You can verify it by clicking on the "Pump, infusion" link on the FDA recall page [here](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfPCD/classification.cfm?ID=FRN).

Comment: i see, then where in API i can get recall's class?

Comment: Unfortunately, this information is not available via the API. But we will work on adding it at some point in the future.